# Blue Screen STOP: 0x0000007B

Tags: windows-7, boot, operating-systems, laptop-repair, system-repair-disc

I am getting blue screen like this:
[image]

What i actually did is I marked my system partition as active, when restarted, I had message

**"BOOTMGR is missing
Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart"**

I inserted **Windows 7 Ultimate x64 CD** and started **Startup Repair**. After it has finished I restarted and got this blue screen.

Any ideas (**except new instalation and formatting the disks**) that might help?

Comment: I have faced the same issue where the system partition get marked as deleted.I am able to recreate it with the same  drive letter but once i reboot it i cant able to login with the same error ""BOOTMGR is missing Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart"".I tried startup recover and it wont worked so Only reinstalled has worked

Comment: I bought new hard drive, and I put the old one in Icy Box SATA Enclosure so I will use it as external, and built in the new one in my laptop and installed new Win 8.1 on it. It is not the solution I wanted but I had to do something because it was urgent and I was running out of time.

Answer (score 0):

This BSoD error means: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE

You can try the following method to fix it, but if this doesn't work, chances are high you'll need to reinstall windows.

During startup, press F8 repeatedly until you get the startup menu which also lists boot into safe mode.

In this menu, you'll find the option `Restore to last configuration known to work` (or something similar.

It should fix your problem, but may undo the changes you made.